# How to configure gemfire as message store for aggregator module in spring cloud data flow

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Link - https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/aggregator/tree/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-processor-aggregator does not list property for gemfire message store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GemfireMessageStore` is configured like this:

```
@ConditionalOnClass(GemfireMessageStore.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = AggregatorProperties.PREFIX,
        name = "message-store-type",
        havingValue = AggregatorProperties.MessageStoreType.GEMFIRE)
@Import(ClientCacheAutoConfiguration.class)
static class Gemfire {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public ClientRegionFactoryBean<?, ?> gemfireRegion(GemFireCache cache, AggregatorProperties properties) {
        ClientRegionFactoryBean<?, ?> clientRegionFactoryBean = new ClientRegionFactoryBean<>();
        clientRegionFactoryBean.setCache(cache);
        clientRegionFactoryBean.setName(properties.getMessageStoreEntity());
        return clientRegionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageGroupStore messageStore(Region<Object, Object> region) {
        return new GemfireMessageStore(region);
    }

}
```

The point is that you always can override that `ClientRegionFactoryBean` with your own.
Or you can take into account that `ClientCacheAutoConfiguration` is based on the `@ClientCacheApplication`, which, in turn, allows you to have a `ClientCacheConfigurer` bean and provide whatever is sufficient for your client cache configuration. Including config and pool. That's right: it is not on the app starter configuration level and you have to right some custom code to be included as a dependency into the final uber jar for target binder-specific application.

More info how to build them is here in Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/docs/Einstein.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#_patching_pre_built_applications

Answer (score 0):

A variety of backend storage options exist through Spring Integration. You can read more about it in [spring-cloud-starter-stream-processor-aggregator/README](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/aggregator/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-processor-aggregator/README.adoc).

Spring Integration docs on this matter are included as a link, and the [Gemfire section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#gemfire-metadata-store) could be useful.

It'd be also useful to review `MessageGroupStore` [implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#reaper), since it is the foundation for the storage option in `aggregator`.

Comment: Thanks Sabby: so far i am already using gemfire messagestore like "simple" messagestore i.e. what happens is that it creates client region "gemfireRegion" for aggregation; issue is i want to use a pre-defined region which already exists in my gemfire cluster but i don't know how & where to define pool & cache.xml config for writing data to remote server. I am already using the code at: [link] (https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/aggregator) to make it work as client cache (removed log4j-to-slf4j). So, is this configurable or does it need additional development efforts ?

Comment: I'm going to ping Artem Bilan, the SME on this area for guidance.

Comment: See my answer how it can be possible with the current state of things. I wonder if `spring-boot-data-geode` can expose some configuration properties we could whitelist...